# Can these hinges be tightened?

Tags: cabinets, hinges, custom-cabinetry

I have a very loose cabinet door seen here: https://imgur.com/Ep3tycf  Can these hinges be fixed/tightened or do they need to be replaced?

Answer (score 1):

The hinges are not broken they need to be tightened to the Base mounts.

It's best to remove the hinges from the door.

The hinge is held to the base mount with a screw in the rear, ( Toward the back of the cabinet), and by hook type catches in the front.

The front hooks need to be engaged first and the hinge slid to the rear to engage the screw.  Then held in place while the screw is tightened to hold the hinge to the base.

Once the hinges are secure, reinstall the door to the hinges.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they are on an angled mounting plate, which the screws have become loosened over time. There may be a screw that keeps the hinge on the mounting plate, that may be loose to. THen again the hinge may be a "quick release" type that has a mall button type to push or a small lips to get the fingertip under to pull to release the hinges. It is located at the very back of the hinge. A picture of the back of the hinge would help me determine.

It looks like it only needs to be tightened.